# What metadata type can be used to extract picklist available values per record type?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

It is not Fields, record types and the Picklist fields. How can I move them from one org to another org?

Answer (score 0):

The picklist values are part of the RecordType metadata, found in the Object file in the objects folder. They are also part of the result set when using RecordType, CustomObject, or a combination of CustomField and RecordType metadata types. See the metadata API documentation for specific details.